# How can an error thrown in a Writable "_write" function be passed back up to the caller?

Tags: node.js, error-handling, stream

How can an error thrown in a Writable "_write" function be passed back up to the caller?

The error message says that the error is uncaught, but the error has to be sent in a callback, so where can it be caught? I have tried putting try/catch blocks in various places inside the getWritable function with no luck.

```
const { pipeline } = require('node:stream/promises');
const { Readable, Writable } = require('node:stream');

function getWritable() {
  const WritableStream = new Writable({
    objectMode: true,
    write(chunk, encoding, callback) {
      console.log(chunk);
      callback(('Throw error here'));
    },
  });
  return WritableStream;
}

try {
  const writestream = getWritable();
  const readstream = Readable.from('1,xcx\n2,xy\n3,xz');
  pipeline(
    readstream,
    writestream,
  );
} catch (err) {
  console.log(`Can error be caught here? ${err}`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Since pipeline returns a promise, use a promise catch instead of a try/catch.

```
    const { pipeline } = require('node:stream/promises');
    const { Readable, Writable } = require('node:stream');

    function getWritable() {
      const WritableStream = new Writable({
        objectMode: true,
        write(chunk, encoding, callback) {
          console.log(chunk);
          callback(('Throw error here'));
        },
      });
      return WritableStream;
    }

    const writestream = getWritable();
    const readstream = Readable.from('1,xcx\n2,xy\n3,xz');
    pipeline(
      readstream,
      writestream,
    ).catch((err) => {
      console.log(`Can error be caught here? ${err}`);
    });
```